# Is there any Excel bulit-in function for SUMPRODUCT IF?

Tags: excel

I have a table (a single table) like the picture below. to find the total $ Order 1, I can use SUMPRODUCT(Price,QTY1), SUMPRODUCT(Price,QTY2), however I would like to know the total $ order but devised into A,B,C.  The important things I really like to keep structure of the table.

[image]

Is there any function like SUMPRODUCTIF. If not, is there anyway to make achieve what I would like to achieve?

I could make another column and do the QTY*Price to do the SUMIF. However, it adds extra columns

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413278/sumproduct-over-sets-of-cells-not-contiguous

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Price*QTY1*(Category="A"))
```

should do the job, with Category being the name of your "Product Category" column (that containing the letters "A", "B", "C").

Comment: is there anyway that I can choose whole column like SUMPRODUCT(A:A*B:B*(C:C="A")) and it not return #VALUE!?

Comment: I assume you have Excel 2007 or a later version. #VALUE error is not a result of using the whole column but [probably] through trying to multiply text values - try a modified syntax like this =SUMPRODUCT(A:A,B:B,(C:C="A")+0)