# Sumproduct on non-contiguous data

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to use sumproduct to multiply two sets of non-contiguous data together. The answer using an embedded CHOOSE function at [SumProduct over sets of cells (not contiguous)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413278/sumproduct-over-sets-of-cells-not-contiguous/22621322#22621322?newreg=ad3bc6ce5d99483fbcc86611ba14aee6) is very close to what I need but I obviously do no fully understand the Sumproduct criteria. If I take that example and, say have 16 rows of data in two columns. If I use the formula

`=SUMPRODUCT(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},A1:A3, A6:A8, A10:A12,A14:A16),CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},B1:B3,B6:B8,B10:B12,B14:B16))`

then it works perfectly but if I use

`=SUMPRODUCT(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},A1:A4, A6:A8, A10:A12,A14:A16),CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},B1:B4,B6:B8,B10:B12,B14:B16))`

- which is what I need - then I get `#N/A`.

I thought the latter formula would work as both arrays (the selected A column data and selected B column data) are the same size (are they not?).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The ranges within the CHOOSE function need to be the same size as well.  Here's an alternative:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNA(MATCH(ROW(A1:A16)-ROW(A1)+1,{5,9,13},0)),A1:A16,B1:B16)
```